# how to create test data for the condition "Opportunity.LastActivityDate != null"

Tags: unit-test, batch

In my batch class, there is a condition that checks

```js
    if(Opp.lastactivitydate != null || (Opp.LastModifiedDate > Opp.CreatedDate && Date.ValueOf(Opp.LastModifiedDate) <= Opp.renew_opp_reminder__c))
```

I want to know how to create test data for an opportunity that has **LastActivityDate != null**

I have tried:

```js
            //setup
            Account accttest = new Account(
                Name                    = 'TestAcc',
                Company_English__c      = 'TestComp',
                DBD_ID__c               = '12345',
                Tax_ID__c               = '-'
            );
            insert accttest;
            
            Opportunity opptest = new Opportunity(
                Name                            = 'Test opp ',
                CloseDate                       = System.today().addMonths(1),
                Policy_Effective_Date__c        = System.today(),
                Renew_Opp_Reminder__c           = System.today(),
                AccountId                       = accttest.Id,
                StageName                       = 'Qualification',
                Renew_From_Lost__c              = true,
                Catch_Up_Noti_Send__c           = true
            );
            insert opptest;
```

I can't add **LastActivityDate = System.today()** because the field is not writeable. Please help me.

Comment: Please refer this help article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386257&type=1

Comment: I have just tried the following article, and I can now set the LastActivityDate, but when I run the test, it's still not getting into the condition. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You might have to check what values you are using for LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate and renew_opp_reminder__c fields.

Comment: I debug the if condition with those values and get "true" as a result, but the test still does not cover the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Opportunity.LastActivityDate` is set when the Opportunity has a completed Task or an event due date.

> [LastActivityDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm?q=Opportunity)
>
> Type date
>
> Properties Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort
>
> Description Value is one of the following, whichever is the most recent:
>
> - Due date of the most recent event logged against the record.
> - Due date of the most recently closed task associated with the record.

So, your test mock up needs to insert a completed task after inserting the Opportunity

```
insert new Task(
    ActivityDate = Date.today(),
    Subject = 'foo',
    Status = 'Completed',
    WhatId = oppTest.Id
);
```

**Bonus content**

All that being said, if the test you care about is in your batchable `execute()` method and you don't need to do DML on the Opportunity, you can unit test just the `execute()` method by passing in a list of records as SObjects. These SObjects can be constructed with audit fields, autonumber fields, formula fields, etc. using the JSON.serialize/deserialize method. There are frameworks that do this, I like Matt Addy's [SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator)

Even better is to look into the Unit of Work pattern for advanced mocking options once you develop your Apex skills more

Comment: This is working. Thank you so much!